# remove last occurrence of ',' in a file - but not the whole line

Tags: bash

If I have a file containing this:

```
[
{[ ...,..., ]},
{[ ...,..., ]},
{[ ...,..., ]},
{[ ...,..., ]},
]
```

I want to remove that very last comma so I get:

```
[
{[ ...,..., ]},
{[ ...,..., ]},
{[ ...,..., ]},
{[ ...,..., ]}    <----- no comma
]
```

I can't find a simple way to do this so far - most solutions remove the whole line or do line searching which does not match what I am trying. I feel like it would be a `sed` or `awk` command.

Comment: It's slightly hard in `sed` because it only processes one line at a time by default, with no way to go back. But we expect you to demonstrate some research or coding effort. What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Why don't you fix the code that creates the file so it uses proper syntax?

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 1):

```
rev file | sed -z 's/,//' | rev
```

Reverse the file, remove the first comma in zero separated stream, so the first comma in the whole file, and than reverse it again.

Comment: This works for me: `tac file | rev | sed -z 's/,//' | rev | tac`

Answer (score 1):

Using `ed`, which, unlike `sed`, is intended for **ed**iting files and thus allows for things like searching backwards in a file:

```bash
printf "%s\n" '?,$?s/,$//' w | ed -s file
```

will find the last line ending with a comma and remove that comma, then save the file.

I agree with @Barmar in the comments though that a better solution is fixing whatever is generating your file to not include that trailing comma in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

With shell parameter expansion, to *blindly* remove the last comma:

```bash
contents=$(< file)
fixed=${contents%,*}${contents##*,}
echo "$fixed"
```

Using text tools: reverse the file, remove the ending comma on the *first* line that has one, then re-reverse the file

```bash
tac file | awk '!p && /,$/ {sub(/,$/, ""); p = 1} 1' | tac
```

Answer (score 1):

A little different take that should allow for the desired output even if the ',' is not the last character of the line.

Find the last line containing a comma and capture the line number:

```
line_no=$(grep -n ',' t.dat | tail -n 1 | cut -f1 -d:)
```

Then remove the last comma from that specific line no matter where it occurs:

```
awk -v li="${line_no}" 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," } NR==li{ for(i=1; i<NF-1; i++). printf "%s", $i OFS; printf "%s\n", $i "" $NF; next }1' t.dat
```

This can be combined as:

```
awk -v li="$(grep -n ',' t.dat | tail -n 1 | cut -f1 -d:)" 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," } NR==li{ for(i=1; i<NF-1; i++) printf "%s", $i OFS; printf "%s\n", $i "" $NF; next
}1' t.dat
```

t.dat contents:

```
[
{[ ...,..., ]},
{[ ...,..., ]},
{[ ...,..., ]},
{[ ...,..., ]},
]
```

Process t.dat:

```
$ awk -v li="$(grep -n ',' t.dat | tail -n 1 | cut -f1 -d:)" 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
      NR==li{ for(i=1; i<NF-1; i++) printf "%s", $i OFS;
            printf "%s\n", $i "" $NF; next
}1' t.dat
```

Output:

```
[
{[ ...,..., ]},
{[ ...,..., ]},
{[ ...,..., ]},
{[ ...,..., ]}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

if the entire file ends with that chunk, then just do

```
gawk FS  RS='[]][}],\n[]]\n' ORS=']}\n]\n'
nawk $$  RS='[]][}],\n[]]\n' ORS=']}\n]\n'
mawk //_ RS='[]][}],\n[]]\n' ORS=']}\n]\n'

[
{[ ...,..., ]},
{[ ...,..., ]},
{[ ...,..., ]},
{[ ...,..., ]}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk '/,/ && ++count==1{gsub(/,$/,"")}1' <(tac file)|tac
```